# git delete local files but keep files in repo

Tags: git, github

Trying to delete a file locally while keeping the file on the repo. The problem is I can't seem to discard the deleted content. I tried using `git rm`. But using `git rm` will also remove the copy on repo which is not what I want. The only solution I can think of is put the path in `.gitignore`. Are there other solutions?

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

    deleted:    stuff/code
```

Comment: What's wrong with putting the path in `.gitignore` and deleting it using the normal tools of your operating system? That seems like exactly what you should do in this case.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist That won't work. You can't add a file to `.gitignore` if it's already in the repo, that won't do anything.

Comment: @meagar Sorry, reading comprehension.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't really a sensible thing to do, or a workflow Git is meant to support.

If you want to delete the local file, but not affect Git, than you can't use Git. Just use `rm <file>`. That missing file will forever appear as an unstaged change to Git.

If you want to remove the file and prevent Git from constantly showing it as an unstaged change, you can use

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

But again, you really shouldn't have to do this.

Comment: Not sure if I am doing it right. I used `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>`, then delete my file. But it still showed up as deleted under `changes not staged for commit`

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Assuming you're on a reasonably up-to-date Git, it should work fine: http://pastebin.com/dsKbNvcq

Comment: @meagar Got it. Thanks for the clear explanation. Very helpful. Btw, I found the following very helpful for deleting multiple files `git ls-files --deleted -z | xargs -0 git update-index --assume-unchanged`.

Comment: I'm using this as a hack so that I can patch in an already committed external library via symlinking it without git complaining that the files are missing.  Now I can develop on the external library in parallel!

Thanks for the nice answer!